# Counter facebook likes and shares for wordpress current page

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

This php code I use to add a counter of facebook likes and shares.

How do instead of www.google.com address insert current address WordPress website.

```
function facebook_shares($url){

    $fql  = "SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, ";
    $fql .= "total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM ";
    $fql .= "link_stat WHERE url = '".$url."'";

    $apifql="https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=".urlencode($fql);
    $fb_json=file_get_contents($apifql);
    return json_decode($fb_json);

}

$fb = facebook_shares('http://www.gogole.com');

// facebook share count
 echo $fb[0]->share_count;
 echo "<br>";

// facebook like count
 echo $fb[0]->like_count;
 echo "<br>";

// facebook comment count
 echo $fb[0]->comment_count;
 echo "<br>";

 // facebook total count
 echo $fb[0]->total_count;
 echo "<br>";
```

Comment: Where do you want to add that? In every page, just in posts?

Comment: on the front page next to each title and the picture is the number of likes and comments. I need something to put this code: get_permalink ()

Comment: $fb = facebook_shares('get_permalink ()');  -- I tried this but it does not work.

Comment: No, it doesn't work if you arent in a post or page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this.

```
 $path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 $url = 'http://www.yoursite.com' . $path;
```

And then add call the function like this:

```
$fb = facebook_shares($url)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it on the home page but the home page is not a post or page then you really just need it to return your site URL.

```
site_url();
```

Returns your website's URL, so this would work on the home page assuming that it is a custom home.php template (which is the only way I can think of that you are doing it without using a page with a permalink).

If this functionality is needed on other pages as well (pages that have permalinks like posts or pages) then use:

```
get_permalink();
```

But not in quotes the way it is in your comment, so:

```
$fb = facebook_shares(site_url());//custom homepage i.e. http://www.yoursite.com
```

Or:

```
$fb = facebook_shares(get_permalink());//post/page i.e. http://www.yoursite.com/about/
```